# Удалить определенные байты C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет!!

Есть массив байтов, в нем есть слово `<IMAGE>`, мне нужно как-то отфильтровать этот массив, чтобы после раскодировки его не было.

И да была идея, сперва раскодировать этот массив найти в нем это слово и удалить, но потом нужно обратно закодировать, но после этих действий, у меня была проблема с кодировкой, есть ли более нормальный способ?
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: (1) В какой кодировке ваш массив? (2) Что значит «удалить»? Остальные символы должны сдвинуться? Или можно заменить?

Comment: Я получаю этот массив с файла, `FileStream("D:/output.jpg",FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);`

Да должно, ну то есть убрать, чтоб не было этой строки

Comment: Окей, вы почитали массив из файла, допустим, это байты с 1000 по 1500. Преобразовали в строку, удалили подстроку, преобразовали обратно, получили массив байт, более короткий, чем исходный массив. Что вы собираетесь делать с ним дальше?

Comment: Почему у вас возникла проблема с кодировкой? Есть требования к быстродействию? Приведите пример массива байт

Comment: вообщем суть такова, нужно получить файл, и отправить его по сокету. Я пробовал кодировать в ASCII, потом обратно в нормальный вид. Но когда я раскодировал, то там беда, мне не приходил нормально файл.
Либо, нужно правильно выбрать кодировку, но не знаю как это правильно сделать. Пробовал Unicode, там вообще не то.

Comment: @HackMemory: А что вы делали после кодирования назад? Это важно. Покажите лучше ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

> Есть массив байтов, в нем есть слово , мне нужно как-то отфильтровать этот массив, чтобы после раскодировки его не было.

Можно сконвертировать  в массив байт. Когда вам приходит пакет, последовательно перебираете массив на совпадение, не обязательно каждую итерацию проверять все слово, можно побайтово на совпадения. Но таким образом есть вероятность удалить полезный кусок данных, у которого байты совпали.
Даже если вы весь полученный пакет раскодируете как массив символов и будете брутфорсить строку, то все равно остается вероятность удалить полезный блок данных.

> Вообщем суть такова, нужно получить файл, и отправить его по сокету. Я пробовал кодировать в ASCII, потом обратно в нормальный вид.

Кодируйте просто в массив байт через BinaryWriter, подписывайте "начальным словом" (просто уникальный набор байт), записываете длину пакета и сам пакет. На той стороне читаете начальное слово, затем длину пакета, затем весь пакет по длине и распаковываете BinaryReador-ом.